# How to deploy kaa cluster

Tags: kaa

i am developing kaa cluster. anyone got other website to follow? Because i don't really understand how to make a complete kaa cluster. anyone with summary instruction also much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you're familiar with Docker it can be the simpler option : http://kaaproject.github.io/kaa/docs/v0.10.0/Administration-guide/System-installation/Docker-deployment/

Comment: what is the differences by using docker?

Comment: The installation steps are already done as you can see : https://github.com/kaaproject/kaa/blob/master/server/containers/docker/Dockerfile. Then you can easily scale your services using the docker ecosystem (compose swarm...)